# Do serial numbers for X.509 certs need to be strictly sequential or can they be timestamps?

Tags: certificates, certificate-authority, x.509

Serial numbers need to be unique for X.509 certs. But do they need to be strictly sequential or is making them equal to the time that the cert was generated sufficient?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They do not have to be sequential. Furthermore, there are some issues with using predictable serial numbers, as described in this post:

https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/257/unpredictability-of-x-509-serial-numbers

Comment: That kinda makes me wonder what the integer length should be. Normally integers are 32-bits but in the case of X.509 / ASN.1 the sky is the limit. Heck - you have the integer type used for RSA keys with 2048-bit "integers".

Comment: When using unpredictable serial number, there is a danger of collisions. The integers should be large enough to reduce the chance of collisions. One person in the post that I linked in my answer is suggesting 128 or 160 bits, but thatch just a suggestion. There is no official recommendation. It probably also depends on how many certificates you plan to generate.

Comment: There _is_ an official recommendation: for backward compatibility with some deployed implementations, the serial number encoded value should fit in 20 bytes -- thus you can use integers up to 2^159 (DER encoding of an INTEGER is signed, so there must be room for a sign bit).

Answer (score 3):

Just look at [CA/Browser Forum Baseline Requirements](https://cabforum.org/baseline-requirements-documents/) v1.3.0, 7.1. Certificate Profile:

> CAs SHOULD generate non‐sequential Certificate serial numbers that exhibit at least 20 bits of entropy.

and you will know the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I am looking at the [specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2459.txt) and it states that it has to be UNIQUE. It doesn't state it should be sequential or otherwise. Also the value is an "integer".

> 4.1.2.2  Serial number
>
> The serial number is an integer assigned by the CA to each
>   certificate.  It MUST be unique for each certificate issued by a
>   given CA (i.e., the issuer name and serial number identify a unique
>   certificate).

**Edit**,

- I agree with @pineappleman - while the specs don't spell it out - it
  makes sense to *not* have predictability in the serial numbers.
- Also an issue with timestamp is you will have to somehow ensure that 2 Certs
  requested at the same time do not get the same serial number.